# Confusion about conservation of energy with translational and rotational energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

[This](https://ophysics.com/r8.html) simulation has me confused about the conservation of energy. If both blocks have equivalent mass, and the velocity of the COM is equal, then they have translational kinetic energy equal to $K_{translational} =\frac 12(mv^2)$. However, the block on the right also has rotational kinetic energy equal to $K_{rotational} = \frac 12(I\omega^2)$, which means the block on the right has extra rotational energy while having equivalent translational energy to the block on the left. Where does this extra energy come from?

There are some similar questions which have been posted but I haven't found any satisfactory answers.

Answer (score 1):

If the collision is inelastic (e.g. the bullet stuck in the rod) energy is not conserved; in that case, if the mass of the bullet is not small enough, it's better to evaluate the inertial properties of the system rod+bullet.

If the collision is elastic, energy is conserved. The difference of the energy of the rod is opposite to the difference of the energy of the of the bullet: when the bullet is fired close to the tip of the rod, the rod has both translational and rotational contribution but the bullet bounces back at a lower speed if compared with the case where the the bullet is fired in the center of the rod.

*If required, more details tomorrow.*

Comment: First sentence - **kinetic** energy is not conserved.

Comment: Also "macroscopic mechanical" energy (that includes potential energy, that we usually deal with in classical mechanics) is not conserved. Of course, **total** energy of a closed and isolated system is conserved, if we trust the 1st principle of thermodynamics

Comment: -It was not a criticism but an attempt by me to suggest that you include the word *kinetic* (twice) in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The collision between bullet and block is inelastic.
The bullet that hits the block off centre penetrates the block less than the bullet which was aimed at the centre of mass of the block.
More penetration means more kinetic energy lost as more work is done breaking more bonds within the block and more heat is produced.
So less kinetic energy is lost when the bullets is off centre and that extra bit of kinetic energy compared with that when aimed at the centre manifests itself as rotational kinetic energy.
There is less penetration when there is an off-centre collision because the block starts to rotate “away” from the bullet, is the relative velocity between the bullet and the block is less than that with the centre of block collision.

In terms of momentum, linear momentum is conserved  in both cases and if the masses of the blocks and bullets and as is the velocity of the bullets then the vertical velocity of the bullet and block after collision will be the same so they will rise to the same height.
The bullet which hits the block off centre has an initial angular momentum about the centre of the block and as no external torques are acting  then the block and bullet must have the same angular momentum after the collision, so they rotate about the centre if mass.

---

Here is a link to a list of YouTube videos related to the question using the words [bullet block Veritasium](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=bullet+block+Veritasium) in the search engine.